# Chai response for svg

Tags: node.js, svg, content-type, chai

I'm trying to verify that the svg returned by my code is correct using Chai. If I do not set the content-type I can check the res.text as below

```
 return chai.request(app).get('/chart.svg?lat=-39&long=174')
        .then((res: any) => {
            expect(res.text).to.eql('<svg></svg>');
        });
```

But if my server sets the content type like this

```
        res.set('Content-Type', 'image/svg+xml')
        res.status(HttpStatus.OK).send(response);
```

The res.text is missing. As far as I can tell res.content and res.body are no use either.

How can I verify the output is correct when the Content-Type is set to 'image/svg+xml'?

Answer (score 0):

Using answers else where I cobbled together this solution

```
function parseSvgXml (res: any, cb : any) {
    res.body = '';
    res.on('data', (chunk: any) => {
        res.body += chunk;
    });
    res.on("end", function () {
        cb(null, res.body);
    });
}
```

I added a `done` parameter which is called after `end` after it has run the assertions

```
it('should return a current badge as svg', (done) => {

    this.uvcStub = sinon.stub(UVChartServiceClass, 'UVChartService').callsFake((args: any) => {
        return new MockUVChartService('<svg></svg>');
    });

    chai.request(app).get('/current.svg?lat=-39&long=174&sky=cloudy')
        .buffer()
        .parse(parseSvgXml)
        .end((err: any, res: any) => {
            expect(res.type).to.eql('image/svg+xml');
            expect(res.body).to.eql('<svg></svg>');
            done();
        });

});
```